# django-tables2 alternative columns not rendering unless the alternative name matches a model field name

Tags: django-tables2

I'm trying to create some calculated columns in a table and add some columns of related objects in an export.  If I use the name of an existing field on the object, the rendering and export come out ok.  But if the name is novel, the rendering and exporting produce -- (aka None).  I think I'm following the documentation closely.  Where am I going wrong?
Here's my Table.py.  As written `name` (not in the model) produces ---.  If I change `name`  to `last_name` (in the model), I'll get what's expected.  Thanks for the help.

```
from django_tables2 import Table, Column, A

class StudentTable(Table):
    class Meta:
        attrs = {"class": "table table-striped table-sm ",
                 "th": {"class": "col-md-2 position-relative",},
                 "td": {"class": "col-md-2 position-relative"},
        }
    # example of what doesn't work
    name = Column(verbose_name="Name",
                       linkify=("client:student_information", {"pk": A("student__id")}))
    # example of what works
    last_name = Column(verbose_name="Name",
                       linkify=("client:student_information", {"pk": A("student__id")}))

    def render_name(self, record):
        return f"{record.last_name}, {record.first_name}"

     def render_last_name(self, record):
        return f"{record.last_name}, {record.first_name}"
```

The view is nothing special either.  The `AffiliateUserMixin` checks that the user can access this view.

```
class StudentListView(AffiliateUserMixin, ExportMixin, SingleTableView):
    model = Student
    context_object_name = 'students'
    table_class = StudentTable
    template_name = 'pages/other_student.html'
```

Finally the template is nothing special.

```
{% if students %}
  <div>
    <a href="{% export_url "csv" %}" class="offset-7">
      <img src="{% static 'images/favicons/download-as-csv.png' %}" alt="Download csv"  /></a>
    <a href="{% export_url "xlsx" %}" >
      <img src="{% static 'images/favicons/download-as-xls.png' %}" alt="Download xslx"  />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <!--div id="roster"></div-->
    {% render_table table %}
  </div>
{% else %}
<div class="mt-3 mb-3">
  No students are registered.
</div>
{% endif %}
```

UPDATE Post Ben's comment (thanks, Ben!)

The situation is the same.  I tried adding `model = Student to Meta`. I've tried removing the Meta class from the table. It doesn't matter - the results are the same.

The model splits names into two parts (last and first).  No matter what I do with "name", a derived column taken quite literally from the example, it only works if the column name matches a model field.  I've tried including `last_name` and `first_name` as fields and then making them non-visible columns, yet keeping `name`.  I tried a different name for the column.

What's weirder is if I do the same thing with another derived field that runs using another model's *related_name* field, it all works very nicely.  Very strange.  There's one other thing I've noticed.  Student is a subclass of CommonPerson, which is a PolymorphicModel. If the fields are on CommonPerson instead of Student, does that affect things?

I'm hoping someone can find my mistake...

Here's the updated *tables.py*

```
class StudentTable(Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("status", "preferred_language")
        sequence = ("last_name", "status", "preferred_language", "matches",)

        attrs = {"class": "table table-striped table-sm ",
                 "th": {"class": "col-md-2 position-relative",
                        },
                 "td": {"class": "col-md-2 position-relative"},
                 }

    last_name = Column(verbose_name="Name",
                       linkify=("client:student_information", {"pk": A("student__id")}))

    matches = Column(verbose_name="Matches", exclude_from_export=True)
    preferred_language = Column(visible=False)
    whatever = Column(verbose_name="What?")

    def render_status(self, record):
        print("render_status")
        return f"{record.status}".replace('-', ' ')

    def render_matches(self, record):
        print("render_matches")
        return record.get_matches(url_flag=True)

    def value_intake(self, record):
        return record.intake.intake_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y")

    def value_intake_by(self, record):
        return record.intake.interviewer_name

    def render_whatever(self, record):
        print("render_name")
        return f"{record.last_name}, {record.first_name}"
```

and here's the console output (there are two rows in the output):

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
render_status
render_matches
render_status
render_matches
[18/Nov/2022 16:33:27] "GET /other/students/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21770
```

Comment: Try adding `model = Student` to the StudentTable's Meta class.

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  Same situation.  Meta now looks like
```
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("status", "name", ) # tried it without the derived value  name as well
        sequence = ("name", "status", "preferred_language", "first_name",)
```
Added print to render_fns.  When run, the console shows only it entered render_status
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
`render_status`

 render_name is never called.
    def render_name(self, record):
        print("render_name")
        return ...

    def render_status(self, record):
        print(...